# Why is a pointer being returned in function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to take a file of a 2d array of grades (for example, file "grades2.txt") and store it into a 2d array. I am not sure how pointers work, as I haven't got that far yet, so I am not sure why a pointer is being returned.

So far, I have a main function that just plugs in values to the parameters, and I have my read function which opens the file and tries to read the file and put the file's values into the `grades` array.

It is okay if the output is wrong, I just want an array to show.

So far, I have tried to check if the array had the same dimension as the file, but that did not help.

grades2.txt

```
 10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0  50.0
100.0  90.0  80.0  70.0  60.0
 95.0  85.0  75.0  65.0  55.0
 25.2  27.2  29.3  31.2  33.2
 88.9  78.8  68.7  58.6  48.5
 10.1  20.1  30.1  40.1  50.1
100.1  90.1  80.1  70.1  60.1
 95.1  85.1  75.1  65.1  55.1
 25.2  27.3  29.4  31.3  33.3
 88.0  78.9  68.8  58.7  48.6
 10.9  20.8  30.7  40.6  50.5
100.9  90.8  80.7  70.6  60.5
 95.9  85.8  75.7  65.6  55.5
 25.8  27.7  29.6  31.5  33.4
 88.7  78.6  68.5  58.4  48.3
 20.0  30.0  40.0  50.0  60.0
 90.0  80.0  70.0  60.0  50.0
 85.0  75.0  65.0  55.0  45.0
 45.2  47.2  49.3  51.2  53.2
 48.9  58.8  68.7  78.6  88.5
 0.01  0.02  0.03  0.04  0.05
```

code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void read (string filename, double grades[30][5]);

//main function
int main() {
    double grades[30][5];
    read("grades2.txt", grades);
    return 0;
}

void read (string filename, double grades[30][5]){
    ifstream input_file(filename);
    if(input_file.is_open()){
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                input_file >> grades[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << grades << endl;
    }
    input_file.close();
}
```

My result should be

```
grades [30]{{10.0,  20.0,  30.0,  40.0,  50.0}
{100.0,  90.0,  80.0,  70.0,  60.0}
{95.0,  85.0,  75.0,  65.0,  55.0}
{25.2,  27.2,  29.3,  31.2,  33.2}
{88.9,  78.8,  68.7,  58.6,  48.5}
{10.1,  20.1,  30.1,  40.1,  50.1}
{100.1,  90.1,  80.1,  70.1,  60.1}
{95.1,  85.1,  75.1,  65.1,  55.1}
{25.2,  27.3,  29.4,  31.3,  33.3}
{88.0,  78.9,  68.8,  58.7,  48.6}
{10.9,  20.8,  30.7,  40.6,  50.5}
{100.9,  90.8,  80.7,  70.6,  60.5}
{95.9,  85.8,  75.7,  65.6,  55.5}
{25.8,  27.7,  29.6,  31.5,  33.4}
{88.7,  78.6,  68.5,  58.4,  48.3}
{20.0,  30.0,  40.0,  50.0,  60.0}
{90.0,  80.0,  70.0,  60.0,  50.0}
{85.0,  75.0,  65.0,  55.0,  45.0}
{45.2,  47.2,  49.3,  51.2,  53.2}
{48.9,  58.8,  68.7,  78.6,  88.5}
{0.01,  0.02,  0.03,  0.04,  0.05}}
```

Comment: You cannot print a whole array like that: `cout << grades << endl;`. Use another two loops instead.

Comment: I don't see a pointer being returned anywhere, but I do see a pointer being printed to stdout via the `cout << grades << endl;` line.  If you want to print out the contents of the array, you'll need to do a nested-for-loop and print out each of the values individually, as C++ isn't clever enough to print out the array for you as a unit.

Comment: C++ is not Python.  There is no "preformatted" way to print out an array.  You have to get your hands dirty and write the code to print out the individual elements, preferably in a loop.

Comment: ohhh, I got it sorry I have been working with python and I just recently have been learning c++

Comment: I disagree slightly with "C++ isn't clever enough". It's more than clever, but us dumb humans can't agree on what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you don't necessarily have to use arrays for storing the information(like double values) in 2D manner because you can also use dynamically sized containers like `std::vector` as shown below. The **advantage** of using `std::vector` is that you don't have to know the number of rows and columns beforehand in your input file(grades2.txt). So you don't have to allocate memory beforehand for rows and columns. You can add the values dynamically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<fstream>
int main() {
    std::string line;
    double word;

    
    std::ifstream inFile("data.mat");
    
    //create/use a std::vector instead of builit in array 
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
    
    if(inFile)
    {
        while(getline(inFile, line, '\n'))        
        {
            //create a temporary vector that will contain all the columns
            std::vector<double> tempVec;
            
            
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            
            //read word by word(or double by double) 
            while(ss >> word)
            {
                //std::cout<<"word:"<<word<<std::endl;
                //add the word to the temporary vector 
                tempVec.push_back(word);
            
            }      
            
            //now all the words from the current line has been added to the temporary vector 
            vec.emplace_back(tempVec);
        }    
    }
    
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    inFile.close();
    
    //lets check out the elements of the 2D vector so the we can confirm if it contains all the right elements(rows and columns)
    for(std::vector<double> &newvec: vec)
    {
        for(const double &elem: newvec)
        {
            std::cout<<elem<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/x9zGevSuv).